# Помогите с PySerial Странное поведение

Tags: python, arduino, serial, pyserial

Вот так работает

```
com = Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=3)
s = input('> ').encode('utf-8')
com.write(s)
data = com.read(100)
print(data)
```

а если поменять на такое

```
com = Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=3)
s = str('hi').encode('utf-8')
com.write(s)
data = com.read(100)
print(data)
```

не работает...

Ардуина получает строку hi и возвращает hi-hi.
если вводить hi в input, проблем нет, но если это заменить присвоением строки, то не работает.
я пробовал по разному и через b'hi' и bytes('hi', 'utf-8') и просто строкой и через str()
только через input все нормально.
Как починить?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ты забыл символ переноса строки. "Hi\n" input по умолчанию возвращает строку с символом переноса строки.
2. Кодировка ардуино ASCII, никак не UTF8
3. Между операциями read/write желательно добавить небольшой delay.

Comment: input не добавляет перенос строки в конце. Я подозреваю, что отправка Serial буферизируется, по какой-то причине в первом варианте буфер выгружается сразу после записи. Теоретически у Serial должен быть метод flush (как у файловых объектов) для принудительной отправки.

Comment: @Eugene X У ардуино кодировка байтовая, аски и утф8 одинаковые в байтовом виде, я проверял.
с переносом строки разницы нет, пробовал

Comment: @AlgiZ попробуйте делать `com.flush()` после write, теоретически должно заработать. Ну и строки не нужно дополнительно оборачивать в str, в этом нет никакого смысла.